# Jenkins integrate with BitBucket(Mercurial) doesn't pull all cahnges

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I have configure my Jenkins profile with BitBucket (Mercurial). Please see the configuration.

[image]

On Jenkins profile, changes displays correctly as per bitbucket check-in history.

[image]

Jenkins build confirms the success on new builds.

But, on Jenkins server work-space folder I don't see all changes that are supposed to be part of those check-ins

**Wondering why is it sometimes missing to pull some changes part of check-in history.**

Comment: My bad, I was looking at wrong workspace path.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to configure [Bitbucket hook service](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.nerdwin15.stash-stash-webhook-jenkins/server/overview) (Project **Settings**).

This way, *Bitbucket* will notify your *Jenkins* server each repository changes on the targeted *branch*.

Comment: I have Poll SCM H/5 * * * * that should do the job ever 5 minutes. and it does trigger a pull every five minutes if there are changes. But the questin is why is it not pulling all changes

Comment: Because each five minutes it's gonna pull the last commit and use it to the compile process. 

If you configure the Webhook, you gonna have a direct link between Bitbucket and Jenkins. This way, each changes (commit) will be pushed to Jenkinss

Comment: so you are saying it will only pull last commit but all all commits since the last build?